# Specify Template Parameters at Build Time

Tags: c++, templates

I have used templates to implement path policies.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <DefaultPolicy.h>

template<typename PathPolicy = DefaultPolicy>
class FileReader
{
    public:
    double getNextNumber();

    private:
    PathPolicy pp;
    readNumbers() { std::ifstream myFile(pp.path); }; //And so on
 };
```

I implemented:

```
[HEADER]
struct DefaultPolicy
{
   public:
   std::string path
   DefaultPolicy()
} ;

[IMPLEMENTATION]
DefaultPolicy::DefaultPolicy() : path("."){}
```

So now I want to implement lots of different policies like:

```
[HEADER]
struct UnitTestPolicy
{
   public:
   std::string path
   UnitTestPolicy()
} ;

[IMPLEMENTATION]
UnitTestPolicy::UnitTestPolicy() : path("unittests/resources"){}

[HEADER]
struct OperationalPathPolicy
{
   public:
   std::string path
   OperationalPathPolicy()
} ;

[IMPLEMENTATION]
OperationalPathPolicy::OperationalPathPolicy() : path("/sw/cm/resources"){}
```

I'm not sure how to switch my policies.  These are compile-time choices, and I can select the target that I'm building for, but the only idea I have is fall back to macros to make a selection. If I do that, then I don't really need the template abstraction for the policy.

How should I select a policy class at build time?

Comment: That will largely depend on what is the criterion to decide which path policy you should use. Macros work fine if you want the user building the code to be able to pass something like `-DUSE_OPERATIONAL_PATH_POLICY`. If you want to choose depending on platform features or something else, you may be able to use template meta-programming or [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If).

Comment: This is a project that has legacy tentacles, and legacy development environments all over the place.  Some developers are very attached to the comfort of the specific environments, no matter how different it is from what is going to become the QA environment.  We are moving towards trying to do CI builds, and I need to make is possible for Jenkins to set things up while not making my other devs weep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the only idea I have is fall back to macros to make a selection

True.

---

> If I do that, then I don't really need the template abstraction for the policy.

False. The template abstraction helps you to minimize use of the preprocessor and isolate your policies cleanly.

You can also force instantiation of your template class in a `.cpp` file to avoid compile-time overhead caused by templates, as you are aware of all the possible policy types.

---

```
// filereaderimpl.hpp

namespace detail 
{ 
    template<typename PathPolicy>
    class FileReaderImpl { /* ... */ };
}
```

```
// filereader.hpp
#include <fileheaderimpl.hpp>

#ifdef SOME_BUILD_TIME_CHOICE
using FileReader = detail::FileHeaderImpl<SomePolicy>;
#else
using FileReader = detail::FileHeaderImpl<SomeOtherPolicy>;
#endif
```

Comment: I have struggled with seeing when 'using' is anything more than a convenience.  This is a clear winner for being semantically useful.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I misread the problem, the solution below will allow policy selection at runtime, you asked for selection at build time.**

I think your problem would be better served by inheritance.

So you have a base `PathPolicy` (you can call it whatever i.e. `DefaultPolicy`) class and then have other policies inherit from the `PathPolicy` class.

So your `UnitTestPolicy` becomes

```
struct UnitTestPolicy : public PathPolicy
{
   public:
     UnitTestPolicy()
     {
       path = "blah//blah";
     }
} ;
```

Then in your file reader, use the base class only to abstract other implementations of the policy class. That way your file reader doesn't care what the policy is; it's just going to read the file.

Working example [here](http://cpp.sh/5lwe7).